# preg_replace target images within P tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace to change some content, I have 2 different types of images...

```
<p>
    <img class="responsive" src="image.jpg">
</p>

<div class="caption">
    <img class="responsive" src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

I am using preg_replace like this to add a container div around images...

```
function filter_content($content)
    {
        $pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)/i';
        $replacement = '<div class="inner $2">$1</div>';
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
        return $content;
    }
```

Is there a way to modify this so that it only affect images in P tags?  And also vice versa so I can also target images within a caption div?

Comment: a mix of DOMDocument and xpath will get the job done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<body><!-- DOMSTART -->".$content."<!-- DOMEND --></body>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$images = $xpath->query("//p/img");
foreach($images as $img) {
    $wrap = $dom->createElement("div");
    $wrap->setAttribute("class","inner ".$img->getAttribute("class"));
    $img->parentNode->replaceChild($wrap,$img);
    $wrap->appendChild($img);
}
$out = $dom->saveHTML();
preg_match("/<!-- DOMSTART -->(.*)<!-- DOMEND -->/s",$out,$match);
return $match[1];
```

It's worth noting that while parsing arbitrary HTML with regex is a disaster waiting to happen, using a parser with markers and then matching based on those markers is perfectly safe.

Adjust the XPath query and/or inner manipulation as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `html` parser instead of regex, `DOMDocument` for example, i.e.:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<p>
    <img class="responsive" src="image.jpg">
</p>
<div class="caption">
    <img class="responsive" src="image2.jpg">
</div>
EOF;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$images = $xpath->query('//p/img[contains(@class,"responsive")]');
$new_src_url = "some_image_name.jpg";
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $image->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
    $dom->saveHTML($tag);
}
```

Comment: What are the benefits of using this method over regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags